# How to get Lemoon to not mess with my video tag

Tags: lemoon

When I edit the HTML of a blog post and add an HTML5 video tag, Lemoon seems to take the liberty of sizing that video tab and adding an embedded shockwave object. Is there any way to override this behavior and tell Lemoon to leave my video tag alone?

Answer (score 0):

I think its TinyMCE that messes with your markup. You can edit the TinyMCE config file in App_Data\Settings\tinymce-standard.js to suit your needs.